# Interword Spacing in XeTeX is not functioning (Fontdimen)

Tags: spacing, xetex

in Default Lyx PDF output, (I presumed it is pdflatex), I used `fontdimen2/3/4` to control the interword space, stretch and shrink. In a project, I had to use XeTeX for a particular font. However, the `fontdimen2/3/4` doesn't work on the regular text anymore under XeTeX. Only works on `fancyhdr`.

My Preamble as regards to the text sizes are following:

```
 %Set word space
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{%
\fontdimen2\font=0.15em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.15em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
}

%set font size
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{8pt}{8.5pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{20pt}{21pt}\selectfont}
```

In order to test the functioning, I set all `fontdimen` to 0, as you observed in the following example, only the `fancyhdr` is affected. the font I am using is Van Dijck MT Std with Old Style Figures on.

[image: fontdimen to 0]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle accidentally pasted that in, wasn't being relevant, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You should supply an example, in particular the font you're using. Notice that special spacing is used when XeCJK is involved.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question.

Comment: Did you try with other fonts?

Comment: @egreg, just tried Adobe Garamond, Adobe Caslon and the Arial, all have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

my own problem, found the answer. 
I used `ragged2e` to make the type set ragging right. However, it needs to be placed under the `everysel`. if `everysel` is before `ragged2e`, the `fontdimen` won't work.

Comment: Which shows why we always ask for a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). In this particular case, `ragged2e` uses `\spaceskip` for the interword spacing, so the `\fontdimen` parameters are ignored.